# RFID Antenna Simulation using MATLAB

Tags: antenna, matlab, rfid, pcb-antenna

I have designed a PCB with RFID antenna and I want to simulate this antenna. I know I need to use PCB Antenna Design APP in MATLAB for this. My MATLAB version is 2017b, this version only has Antenna Design APP. I couldn't find PCB Antenna Design APP. I tried to download this APP but failed.

What version do I need for PCB Antenna Design APP?

If there is an application that you can recommend instead of MATLAB, I can try them as well. I want to see the S-parameter and impedance graphs.

I don't want to buy Vector Network Analyzer for this process.

Comment: We usually use HFSS or CST Microwave (field solvers) to design & analyze antenna elements.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/antenna/ref/pcbantennadesigner-app.html) for PCB Antenna Designer

> Version History
>
> Introduced in R2021b